# Grails hibernate fetch old data

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

```
void doSomething(batchSize, someList){
    def db = new Sql(datasource)
    db.withTransaction{
        db.withBatch(batchSize){ stmt -> 
            someList.each {
                String sqlStr = ""
                //  do something and prepare sqlStr
                stmt.addBatch(sqlStr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function and when querying again I am getting old data, even though database has been updated. What could be the issue ?? is withBatch asynchronus or something ??

Answer (score 0):

The batch is not executed until the executeBatch method is called on the PreparedStatement. Make sure that you're calling the executeBatch at the end of that closure.
Try this:

```
void doSomething(batchSize, someList) {
    def db = new Sql(datasource)
    db.withTransaction {
        db.withBatch(batchSize) { stmt ->
            someList.each {
                String sqlStr = ""
                //  do something and prepare sqlStr
                stmt.addBatch(sqlStr)
            }
            stmt.executeBatch() // Execute the batch after adding all statements
        }
    }
}
```

In this implementation, executeBatch() is called on the PreparedStatement object stmt after adding all the batch statements. This will execute all the batched SQL statement as a single operation.

Regarding your question about the withBatch method, it is not asynchronous by default. The withBatch method is executed synchronously and each batch statement is added to the batch sequentially. Hope this helps